# YOLO pose estimation Calculate angle position

Tags: yolo, angle, estimation, pose

I cant found a tutorial that teach how calculate angle position between three landmarks in yolo (push-up counter for example)

FYI: i can do it very well on mediapipe

Im installed yolo but i don't know how to landmarks works